# C++ file handling, is_open returning bad

Tags: c++, file-io

If I include the if test in my code the error message is returned and I'm not sure why. 
and when it's not used, my program get's stuck in a loop where it never reaches the end of the file. I don't understand what's going wrong.

```
int countlines()
{
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("questions.txt", ios::in);
    string contents;
    int linenumber = 0;

    //if (myfile.is_open())  
    // {
    while (!myfile.eof())  
    {
        getline( myfile, contents );
        if (contents != "")
        {
            linenumber++;
        }
    }
    cout << "there are " << linenumber << " lines.\n";
    //}else {cout<<"Unable to get file.\n";}

    myfile.close();
    return(linenumber);
}
```

Comment: [`while (!myfile.eof())` is almost always wrong](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5). Where were you taught to do that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it was the only sample code that seemed to work. so I got it off a programming website I assume!

Comment: @Bhuggy: you probably got it from a bad online tutorial like the ["file handling" tutorial on cpluscplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).  Be careful! [cplusplus.com as it sometimes gives bad advice and/or facts](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com).

Comment: @Bhuggy: Reason I ask is so that I can contact the author. You should get yourself [a proper C++ book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources) which, when found on that list, are trustworthy; random tutorials on the internet are not trustworthy.

Comment: @AndréCaron yeah it probably was from there, most of my searches seem to end up on cplusplus forums or tutorial pages.

Answer (score 3):

What's going on is that your file is not being opened. That's why `is_open` fails.

Then, when you comment out the check, you're breaking your loop because you're iterating incorrectly (see my comment) and not detecting stream failures (`.eof()` will *never* be `true` on that stream).

Make sure that the file is in the right place, and that it is accessible.

Comment: How would I make my file accessible? It's in the right place (in the program file with all the other code files) so I can only assume something's stopping it from being accessed.

Comment: Bhuggy, you're opening the file with a relative path. Are you sure your program's current working directory at the time you call `countlines` is really the one that contains your file? Use an absolute path, or call `chdir` to make sure the current directory is what you think it is.

Comment: @Bhuggy: It doesn't really matter where the program file is. In fact, the process doesn't even _know_ where the program file is! What matters is the _current working directory_ of the environment that invoked the executable.

Comment: @RobKennedy is there any good tutorials on using paths? I only ask as I was looking for something to easily navigate files but i couldn't really find anything that was appropriate, but maybe that's because i was looking for an easy way to do things and ignored the good stuff.

Comment: @Bhuggy: As I said before, you want _a peer-reviewed book_, not some "tut".

Answer (score 2):

When using `std::istream` and `std::ostream` (whose `std::fstream` implements), the recommended usage is to directly use the stream in a bool context instead of calling `eof()` function because it only return `true` when you managed to read until the last byte of the file. If there was any error before that, the function will still return `true`.

So, you should have written your code as:

```
int countlines() {
    ifstream myfile;
    int linenumber = 0;
    string linecontent;
    myfile.open("question.txt", ios::in);
    while (getline(myfile, linecontent)) {
        if (!linecontent.empty()) {
            ++linenumber;
        }
    }
    return linenumber;
}
```

Comment: Actually it's mostly because it doesn't set `eof` until a read has _already_ failed due to EOF. However, yes, you gain checks for the other flags too by testing the stream directly.

Answer (score 2):

The correct idiom for reading a file line-by-line in C++ is using a loop like this:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(file,line);)
{
    // process line.
}
```

Inserting this in your example (+fixing indentation and variable names)  gives something like this:

```
int countlines(const std::string& path)
{
    // Open the file.
    std::ifstream file(path.c_str());
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        return -1; // or better, throw exception.
    }

    // Count the lines.
    int count = 0;
    for (std::string line; std::getline(file,line);)
    {
        if (!line.empty()) {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Note that if you don't intend to process the line contents, you can actually skip processing them using [`std::streambuf_iterator`](http://drdobbs.com/184401357), which can make your code look like:

```
int countlines(const std::string& path)
{
    // Open the file.
    std::ifstream file(path.c_str());
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        return -1; // or better, throw exception.
    }

    // Refer to the beginning and end of the file with
    // iterators that process the file character by character.
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> current(file);
    const std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end;

    // Count the number of newline characters.
    return std::count(current, end, '\n');
}
```

The second version will completely bypass copying the file contents and avoid allocating large chunks of memory for long lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It will also (hopefully) give you an idea why the file open is failing...

```
int countlines()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("questions.txt");
    string contents;
    int linenumber = 0;

    if (myfile.is_open())  
    {
        while (getline(myfile, contents))  
        {
            if (contents != "")
                linenumber++;
        }
        cout << "there are " << linenumber << " lines." << endl;        
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to get file (reason: " << strerror(errno) << ")." << endl;

    return linenumber;
}
```

Comment: The iteration is still not right. And is fstream opening failure guaranteed to set `errno`? Good call if so; but I'm not sure.

Comment: Not sure if errno is guaranteed to be set but a quick test using g++ on OS X confirms it works here and I would imagine it works on Linux too. Fingers crossed for Windows. Thought it may help the OP figure out the reason for the open failure.

Comment: The iteration is wrong, so you get a downvote. No need to be snippy.

Comment: getline() call moved into the loop condition as others have pointed out is recommended practice.

Comment: Much better. It's not just "recommended practice"; it completely changes the behaviour of the loop.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. fstream doesn't guarantee so set errno but in practice it should be set. If one doesn't use errno, then you don't have a portable way of determining the nature of the exception, as using what() does not return a consistent string (the string even changes in the face of locale etc). The value of errno is not consistent too, but at least it is consistent within an environment/OS, which cannot be said of an exception string.